# Cast video android - Shows red letters "SAMPLE" on tv

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cast

so I used this guide to create a google cast video android app:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#4

I keep getting huge letters saying SAMPLE in front of the video on the tv. I have no clue what causes this problem. If it's the app itself or the wrong receiver ID or even the TV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove "Sample" it's intended as its a sample app. You have to direct your app to a different receiver.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replay. I got it working now, but only to cast videos from https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/mp4/

The video from my server won't play though, only those from there. I even use https:// and the server is reachable. The video also plays on the phone, but wont cast.
I get errors like:
I/MediaNotificationService: actionsProvider == null
failed to get folderSize and Fail to get file list com.google.sample.cast.refplayer